# Storing numbers from a file into an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a file called "input.txt" with the numbers below. I want to read this file and make it into an array. The first integer - 10 tells the number of indexes or elements in the array, so 10 spots. The code below is what I have done so far I just don't know how to read the input.txt from the first line

```
    10
    3
    4
    5
    6
    4
    4
    5
    6
    3
```

size of this array will be the first number in the file

```
static void display(int[] numArray) {
    System.out.println("Array contents: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(numArray[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] numberArray = new int[10];

    System.out.println("Enter the name of your file (including file extension): ");
    String filename = input.next();

    int count = 0;

    try {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        int result = in.nextInt();

        while (in.hasNextInt()&& count < 10) {
            numberArray[count] = result;
            count = count + 1;
            result = in.nextInt();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("That file was not found. Program terminating...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    display(numberArray);

}
```

Comment: Well you need to put the it in a while loop... int result needs to be in the while loop

Comment: You should close the Scanner after you're done reading from the file. The best and easiest way to do that is with a [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need create the array with size of first line and, if you need, put in the array. You can try these ways:

If you are using Java 7 or above, you can try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        final int[] numberArray = new int[10];

        System.out.println("Enter the name of your file (including file extension): ");
        final String filename = input.next();

        try (final Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename))) {
            final int count = in.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; in.hasNextInt() && i < count; i++) {
                numberArray[i] = in.nextInt();
            }
            display(numberArray);
        } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("That file was not found. Program terminating...");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using java before 7, try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {

        System.out.println("Enter the name of your file (including file extension): ");
        final String filename = input.next();

        int[] numberArray = null;
        try (final Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename))) {
            final int count = in.nextInt();

            numberArray = new int[count];

            for (int i = 0; in.hasNextInt() && i < count; i++) {
                numberArray[i] = in.nextInt();
            }
            display(numberArray);
        } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("That file was not found. Program terminating...");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If the first line should be added to the array, put `numberArray[0] = count;`
 below `numberArray = new int[count];` and initialize for step with **1**.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (untested). Note how the size is being grabbed first, the array created based on that, and then the rest of the file is being read.

```
static void display(int[] numArray) {
    System.out.println("Array contents: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(numArray[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the name of your file (including file extension): ");
    String filename = input.next();

    int count = 0;
    int[] numberArray;
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        int size= in.nextInt();
        numberArray = new int[size];
        int result;
        while (in.hasNextInt()&& count < size) {
            numberArray[count] = result;
            count = count + 1;
            result = in.nextInt();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println("That file was not found. Program terminating...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    display(numberArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it still wont work, Im getting cannot find symbol at displayArray(numArray);

Comment: thats because the array should be defined before the try block and then initialised once the size has been obtained. updated the answer